# Should I shuffle the Visage tokens after an investigator gets devoured?

Tags: arkham-horror, arkham-horror-innsmouth-horror

The Ancient One named **Ghatanothoa** has a power called **Annihilating Gaze**.

> While Ghatanothoa stirs in his slumber, place the eight visage tokens facedown on this sheet. Each time an investigator gains 2 or more Clue tokens at once, he must turn a visage token faceup. If it has Ghatanothoa's face on it, he is devoured. If not, leave the token faceup. Once four visage tokens are faceup, turn them facedown and shuffle the visage tokens.

Perhaps I'm being overly pedantic, but it isn't clear what happens if Ghatanothoa's face is turned up and there are not yet 4 visage tokens face up.

After the investigator is devoured, are all 8 tokens shuffled?  Is the next pick "free"?  I was unable to locate a clarification for this in the rulebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From page 9 of the Innsmouth Horror rulebook:

> Remember, leave visage tokens faceup after revealing them 
>   unless either Ghatanothoa’s face is revealed or there are 
>   four visage tokens faceup after revealing the new token.

So while it doesn't explicitly tell you to turn them facedown and shuffle them, I'd say it's clear enough. So yes, no freebie clue harvesting after your poor friend gets devoured!

Comment: Thats what we did but the vagueness bothered us.